# neo4j load csv taking infinite time to execute my query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am loading the data into neo4j using loadcsv function. I have two types of nodes -Director and Company.
The below command is working fine and is executing within 50milisec.

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///Director.csv" AS line
CREATE(:Director {DirectorDIN:line[0]})

Load csv from "file:///Company.csv" AS line
Create(:Company{CompanyCIN:line[0]})
```

Now I am trying to build the relationship between the two nodes which is taking an infinite time to execute my query. Here is the simple query that I am trying.

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///CompanyDirector.csv" AS line
match(c:Company{CompanyCIN:toString(line[0])}),(d:Director{DirectorDIN:toString(line[1])}) create (c)-[:Directed_by]->(d)
```

I have also tried:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///CompanyDirector.csv" AS line
match(c:Company{CompanyCIN:line[0]}),(d:Director{DirectorDIN:line[1]}) create (c)-[:Directed_by]->(d)
```

It is taking an infinite time. Please let me know what can be the issue over here?

**Information:**
The CSV file does not contain more than 20k records.
CompanyCIN is alphanumeric 
DirectorDIN is numeric in nature

Comment: Do you have any indexes defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to create some schema constraint in your database :

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT on (n:Company) ASSERT n.CompanyCIN IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT on (n:Director) ASSERT n.DirectorDIN IS UNIQUE;
```

Without thoses constraints the complexity of your query is **N*M**, where **N** is the number of `Company` nodes and **M** the number of `Director`.
To see what I mean, you can `EXPLAIN` your query before and after the creation of thoses constraints.

Moreover, you should also use the `PERIODIC COMMIT` on your `LOAD CSV` query, like that :

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///CompanyDirector.csv" AS line
MATCH (c:Company{CompanyCIN:line[0]})
MATCH (d:Director{DirectorDIN:line[1]}) 
CREATE (c)-[:Directed_by]->(d)
```

Comment: It helped.. thanks a lot for your time and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue was that you did not have [indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) on `:Company(CompanyCIN)` and `:Director{DirectorDIN)`. Without the indexes, neo4j is forced to evaluate **every possible pair** of `Company` and `Director` nodes for **every** line in your CSV file. That takes a lot of time.

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Company(CompanyCIN);

CREATE INDEX ON :Director{DirectorDIN);
```

*By the way, creating the corresponding uniqueness constraints (as suggested by @logisma) has the side-effect of creating these indexes, but the issue was not caused by missing uniqueness constraints.*

In addition, you should avoid creating duplicate `Directed_by` relationships by using `MERGE` instead of `CREATE`.

This should work better (you can use the `USING PERIODIC COMMIT` option, as suggested by @logisima if you have ):

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000 LOAD CSV FROM "file:///CompanyDirector.csv" AS line
MATCH (c:Company {CompanyCIN:line[0]})
MATCH (d:Director {DirectorDIN:line[1]}) 
MERGE (c)-[:Directed_by]->(d)
```